# Eclipselink updates entity field when it is not changed

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have two entities with @OneToMany (Entity1) & @ManyToOne (Entity2) bidirectional relation. In @OneToMany relation I have @Cascading{Cascade.ALL}. But when I change boolean property which is initially false, of the entity with @ManyToOne relation to the true and then back to the false within a transaction or a method, it causes database to trigger update query to set entity's boolean to false, which seems to wrong because it is initially false and at the commit time still false.
I'm using eclipselink 2.5.1 as jpa implementation. What can be causes?

```
update(Integer entityId) {
    tx.begin();
    Entity1 entity1 = findEntity(entityId);
    for(Entity2 entity2 : entity1.getEntity2List()) {
        entity2.setBooleanProperty(Boolean.TRUE);//which is initially false, we set it to true for programmatic purpose ;
        ...
        entity2.setBooleanProperty(Boolean.FALSE);//at this point db updates boolean property to false
    }
    em.merge(entity1);
    tx.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I'd guess that EclipseLink just takes the first change as marking that field to be "changed". There is likely no logic to save the original value and consequently check if it is reset to the original value (it would be a significant overhead to have to save all original values of all fields).

Hence when you merge the object that field is marked as having been changed whilst detached. Consequently it gets updated in the datastore. Can't say that it's "wrong", since its a trade-off between storing all original values of all fields and adding checks, against a single datastore update statement (and the user has it in their hands to get their desired behaviour by only updating a field when it is going to be merged with that value).

Comment: That would be problem if I keep history of all changes using eclipselink's history support. It records all updates even there is no need to save unnecessary ones like this, and it is also overhead if I change a lot of entities this way.